# Passing data to another page using AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to pass data from one page to another using AngularJs service but whatever value I set in the variables in the service on one page, it is lost on redirection. Is there any particular way to perform the redirection? Below is the flow of my code

//Created a service to pass data

```
 angular.module('Test').service('TestService', function() {
     var new_data;
     this.addData = function(page_data) {
          new_data = page_data;
      }

      this.getData = function(){
          return new_data;
      }
    });
```

//Code in controller A:

```
 TestService.addData(data);
 $window.location.href = "/static/html/buyer-cart-confirmation.html"
```

//Code in controller B:

```
data = TestService.getData();
```

No data is received in controller B. Can somebody please help me with this.
 Thank you!

Comment: Angular wont work between cross redirecting

Comment: That only is possible when using `ngRoute`. however you can use `cookies`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use session storage to serialize / deserialize data across different instances of angular within the same session (tab), and you can use local storage to do the same thing across sessions, (new tab). Here is the code for both:

#### Session Storage

```
class SessionStorageService

    setStorage:(key, value) ->
        json =  if value? then JSON.stringify value else null
        sessionStorage.setItem key, json

    getStorage:(key)->
        JSON.parse sessionStorage.getItem key

    pageData1:(value=null) ->
        @accessor 'pageData1', value

    pageData2:(value=null) ->
        @accessor 'pageData2', value

    # more data values defined here

    accessor:(name, value)->
        return @getStorage name unless value?
        @setStorage name, value

angular
.module 'app.Services'
.service 'sessionStorageService', SessionStorageService
```

#### Local Storage Service

```
class LocalStorageService

    setStorage:(key, value) ->
        json =  if value? then JSON.stringify value else null
        localStorage.setItem key, json

    getStorage:(key)->
        JSON.parse localStorage.getItem key

    clear: ->
        @setStorage(key, null) for key of localStorage

    pageData1:(value=null) ->
        @accessor 'pageData1', value

    pageData2:(value=null) ->
        @accessor 'pageData2', value

    # more data values defined here
    accessor:(name, value)->
        return @getStorage name unless value?
        @setStorage name, value

angular
.module 'app.Services'
.service 'localStorageService', LocalStorageService
```

With that said, you need to ask yourself why you are redirecting to a different page with any expectation that your state will somehow be preserved?

Angular is typically used for Single Page Applications that use routing frameworks like [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) to manage state transformations, rather than the old-school, click-and-refresh-the-page model.

In other words, you should not redirect unless you intend on starting a brand new Angular application.

Answer (score 0):

I think your logic is wrong, and since you don't provide a Plunker I can't test it at the moment. I think you should go with smth like:

```
angular.module('Test').service('TestService', function() {

    this.addData = function(page_data) {
        this.new_data = page_data;
    };
    return this;
});
```

and then you access your data like this:

```
TestService.new_data
```

I think it will work like this.